# Problema para mostrar, eliminar y actualizar elementos en el resumen del carrito usando AJAX (App en Django)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

Estoy desarrollando una web de un ecommerce y me encuentro con un problema en el cual los elementos del carrito no se eliminan ni se actualizan. He verificado que las solicitudes AJAX se envían correctamente al servidor y parece que los datos se procesan sin errores.

Además de este problema, también tengo dificultades para acceder correctamente a los datos de los elementos del carrito en el resumen. Aunque los elementos vacíos se agregan al carrito con la cantidad correcta, no se muestran las imágenes, títulos y otras características asociadas a los productos.

Estoy revisando la lógica de mi aplicación del carrito y cómo manejo las solicitudes AJAX, pero no logro identificar dónde podría estar el error.

***cart.py***

```
    def add(self, book, quantity=1):
        book_id = str(book.id)
        if book_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[book_id] = {'quantity': quantity, 'price': str(book.get_book_price())}
        else:
            self.cart[book_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def delete(self, book_id):
        book_id = str(book_id)
        if book_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[book_id]
            self.save()

    def update(self, book_id, quantity):
        book_id = str(book_id)
        if book_id in self.cart:
            self.cart[book_id]['quantity'] = quantity
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
            product_ids = self.cart.keys()
            books = Book.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
            cart = self.cart.copy()

            for book in books:
                book_id = str(book.id)
                cart[book_id]["book"] = book

            for book in cart.values():
                book["price"] = Decimal(book["price"])
                book["total_price"] = book["price"] * book["quantity"]
                yield book
```

***views.py (de cart)***

```
def cart_summary(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/summary.html', {'cart': cart})

def cart_add(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    response = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book_id = request.POST.get('book_id')
        quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=book_id)
        cart.add(book=book, quantity=quantity)

        cart_qty = cart.__len__()
        response = {
            'qty': cart_qty,
        }
    return JsonResponse(response)

def cart_delete(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    response_data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book_id = request.POST.get('book_id')
        cart.delete(book_id=book_id)

        cart_qty = cart.__len__()
        cart_total = cart.get_total()

        response_data = {
            'qty': cart_qty, 
            'total': cart_total
        }
        
    return JsonResponse(response_data)

def cart_update(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    response_data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book_id = request.POST.get('book_id')
        quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
        cart.update(book_id=book_id, quantity=quantity)
        
        cart_qty = cart.__len__()
        cart_total = cart.get_total()

        response_data = {
            'qty': cart_qty, 
            'total': cart_total
        }
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

***scripts AJAX***

```
  // Delete Item
  $(".delete-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var book_id = $(this).data("index");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '{% url "cart:cart_delete" %}',
      data: {
        book_id: book_id,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
      },
      success: function (json) {
        $('.product-item[data-index="' + book_id + '"]').remove();
        $('#total').html("Precio total: Bs." + json.total);
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},
    });
  });

  // Update Item
  $(".update-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var book_id = $(this).data("index");
    var quantity = $("#select" + book_id).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '{% url "cart:cart_update" %}',
      data: {
        book_id: book_id,
        quantity: quantity,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
      },
      success: function (json) {
        $('#total').html("Precio total: Bs." + json.total);
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Sabes que json es de tipo `string`?

Asumiendo que las solicitudes AJAX se envían correctamente...
Necesitas transformar la respuesta json en un objeto.

```
success: function (json) {
  const respuesta = JSON.parse(json)  // <-- Mira aqui
  $('.product-item[data-index="' + book_id + '"]').remove();
  $('#total').html("Precio total: Bs." + respuesta.total);
},
```

Documentación:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse